# terminal emulator which auto closes after execution but stays open if there was an error during execution

Tags: compiling, terminal-emulator

I have an automatic build script; it uses a makefile which starts different ant scripts depending on the target.

I start it using xterm (I have a shortcut on the desktop).
It works fine, but if I want to check if the execution was successful, I can't close the terminal automatically.

Is there a terminal emulator which won't auto-close if there was an error during execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to open a terminal to run one command and close the terminal. This is a highly unusual workflow outside the Windows world. The usual workflow is to have a terminal open permanently, and run commands in it when needed. Or, when the command is a build command, work in an IDE and have it invoke the build process.

If you insist in creating a new terminal each time (a bad idea, because that will make messages from prior builds immediately unavailable), you can make the terminal wait in case of error by inserting a shell snippet that checks the return status, and waits for input if there is an error.

```
xterm -e sh -c 'ant mytarget || read line'
```

If the build process completes successfully, the terminal window will be closed immediately. If the build process fails, the terminal window will be closed after you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

So do not put `exit` in the end of the script and/or check return code...

Comment: this does not work with xterm it closes unless  you set the -hold flag  but you are right  I can check the exit code and wait for user input if there is an error  still I hope there is a terminal emulator which can do this

Comment: @sherif just change the command that the shortcut runs. `make foobar || read` will wait for an <ENTER> keypress if make fails.

Answer (score 0):

I think what Jiri meants was that you should use xterm, without -hold, and change your build script to only exit if it completes successfully. If there is an error, have your build script stop and wait for a key press from the user. If your build script is a bash script, just use the read statement:

```
read unused_var
```